# Does a single 5-color card satisfy Spirit of Resistance?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Spirit of Resistance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=22968) require you to have one card of each color or does a single card with all 5 colors satisfy its requirement?

**Oracle Text**:

> As long as you control a permanent of each color, prevent all damage that would be dealt to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the rulings at the bottom of the linked Gatherer page ([again](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?printed=false&multiverseid=22968) for reference), you'll see the following ruling for this card:

> **10/4/2004:** A permanent which is of multiple colors counts as each of its colors.

Comment: Wow, OK, that was the first place I looked and didn't see it. Couldn't be clearer though. Thanks!